# How can i have my jar open itself in terminal automatically

Tags: java, terminal

I need my jar after double click to open itself in a terminal window to handle IO (on mac specifically)

Things ive tried:

the closest thing ive found to a solution is
`p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal");`
which opens a terminal window but if i try and execute a command p = `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal [my command]");` or if i try and add a path `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal /Users/me/Desktop/myJar.jar");` a terminal window will no longer open. Ive also seen a solution recommending "AppleScript" but it appears my jdk (17) does not include any scriptManagers and `ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("AppleScript");` returns a null ScriptEngine

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I haven't been able to manage that either. I usually just make a batch (or bash, if Linux) script that starts the jar, so it comes with a terminal for free.

Comment: right thats what im doing in windows but i cant find a good mac alternative

Comment: If you are looking for a mac-specific solution, it would be a good idea to put that in the question next time.

Comment: edited question